# Google Spreasheet: get unique values from two columns into a single one

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I need to get unique values from two columns into a single one. 
I tried with formula `unique(A:B)` but **this formula creates two columns** for the results. I need the results to be in a single column. Take a look at my capture:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try (in D3):

```
=unique({A3:A;B3:B})
```

The braces with the semicolon create a stacked column of A and B.

To avoid blanks, you could try:

```
=filter(unique({A3:A;B3:B}), unique({A3:A;B3:B})>"")
```